# ElasticSearch in Windows docker image vm max map count

Tags: windows, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and Elasticsearch.
I am using a Windows 7 machine. I am using `docker-compose up` to bring up the docker container. My yml file has

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:5.1.1
  environment:
    ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
```

along with other linked images.
I am using docker to bring up the elasticsearch image and when I do so I get the following error

```
[36melasticsearch_1   |←[0m ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
[36melasticsearch_1   |←[0m max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530]  is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[36melasticsearch_1   |←[0m [2017-02-08T11:06:51,752][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
```

I googled for a solution and everywhere they suggest to use 
`sudo sysctl vm.max_map_count=262144`, but in Windows `sysctl` is not available. No clear steps are given for Windows.

Some other Docker images are up and running on my machine so Docker is working.

Can someone give any clues to solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I found the answer in one of the suggestions below. You might save people time in the future if you tick the right answer.

Answer (score 125):

I have been stuck for months on this problem, the solution is launch the following commands on cmd.exe (try Powershell or Bash if cmd doesn't work), [as stated in the official Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_set_vm_max_map_count_to_at_least_262144):

```
1) wsl -d docker-desktop
2) sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

And you are ready to start Elasticsearch!

Comment: Saved me! only thig is, didn't work for me when ran that in CMD, but running that in PowerShell fixed the issue.

Comment: Saved me .. Thanks

Comment: If `wsl -d docker-desktop` does not bring you into the docker-desktop subsystem, you will be prompt `sysctl` is not found when you execute the second command. In this case, try uncheck "Use the WSL 2 based engine" in the docker desktop app and then check it again.

Comment: Thank you very much, saved me hours of searching

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work after restart

Answer (score 21):

Currently, following [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5202), the way to make it work is by `wsl -d docker-desktop` and `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` there.

Some people got it to work persistently by `echo "vm.max_map_count = 262144" > /etc/sysctl.d/99-docker-desktop.conf` or `echo -e "\nvm.max_map_count = 262144\n" >> /etc/sysctl.d/00-alpine.conf`, but none of these worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as `docker-machine ssh` was not an option.

Comment: yeah, I forgot to mention that since I was dealing with WSL, `docker-machine ssh` wasn't an option either!

Comment: Good answer people forget not everyone wants to use a different distro. I have Docker-Desktop with WSL 2 using Debian

Comment: Please use this commands

`wsl -d docker-desktop`
`echo 262144 >> /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count`

Comment: Good Job 100% working

Answer (score 10):

the only thing that worked for me as permanent solution was adding this line to the `.wslconfig` (should be in your windows user directory %userprofile%)

```
[wsl2]
kernelCommandLine="sysctl.vm.max_map_count=262144"
```

thanks to @NotTheDr01ds for finding the solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69294687/1972133

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#wslconfig

Comment: And shutdown docker, shutdown wsl2 with `wsl --shutdown`, then start docker

Answer (score 8):

Elasticsearch have a fix for this.

This worked for me on Win 10 Pro Version 10.0.19042.685, Docker Engine v20.10.0     Using ES 7.10

The problem is on the host linux machine (WSL2) not the containers.

see section Windows with Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_set_vm_max_map_count_to_at_least_262144

-d distribution (eg not ubuntu)

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

After that my 3 node cluster docker-compose launched successfully.

Comment: Hi, good answer, but is there anyway to keep this permanent? It seems I keep having to do this.

Answer (score 6):

You can set up vm.max_map_count using following commands:

`docker-machine ssh`

`sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`

Comment: This works if you SSH into the docker-machine. I am doing this on Windows 7 with Docker toolbox(legacy requirement).

Comment: What is wrong if my machine doesn't have the command `docker-machine`?

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the approaches and non worked for me... However I was able to set it permanently like this.

1. Create a bat file for example (set_vm_max.bat)
2. Write the command inside the file  "wsl  -d **docker-desktop** sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144"
3. Now will have to copy the file to the startup location, press "Windows + R"
4. Type "shell:startup" and press Enter.
5. Copy the file you just created to start location.

To verify it works:

1. Reboot
2. wsl -d docker-desktop
3. cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count

Answer (score 2):

You started Elasticsearch in normal or production mode, which from Version 5 contains bootstrap checks, and if they fail Elasticsearch won't start.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html

However you can run the development mode on Windows, which only resolves into warnings. Just try to run the image of elastic itself.

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" \
 -e "transport.host=127.0.0.1" \
 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.0
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Answer (score 2):

In Docker Desktop

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

In Rancher Desktop

```
wsl -d rancher-desktop
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Rancher with provisioning scripts

- https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/how-to-guides/provisioning-scripts/
- https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/how-to-guides/increasing-open-file-limit/

Answer (score 1):

As I was new to this Docker I am confused with the basics. I found the solution for my problem now.
In the docker installed in windows there is an Oracle VM Linux box created. I opened that and then there I added the `sudo sysctl vm.max_map_count=262144` after which the problem was solved.

Comment: how/where did you find that?

Answer (score 1):

Unintentionally found that simpler solution for wsl2 user, just run following command in your default wsl2 distribution shell

`sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`

for example:

[image]

Comment: how to open such shell?

Comment: @Luck-Aron If you mean the shell, its windows terminal, if you mean the info, install and run `neofetch` bro.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer suggested in one of the comments worked well (persisted until machine reboot) in Windows 10,  WSL2:

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
echo 262144 >> /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

Answer (score 0):

- wsl -d docker-desktop
- vi /etc/wsl.conf

add these lines at the end:

```
[boot]
kernelCommandLine = "sysctl.vm.max_map_count=262144"
```

Then restart docker-desktop.

Comment: better put into `.wslconfig` since `wsl.conf` will reset after reboot. like this:
`
[wsl2]
kernelCommandLine = "sysctl.vm.max_map_count=262144"
`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#wslconfig

Answer (score -1):

Elasticsearch required minimal value `262144` for variable `vm.max_map_count`.

In linux, show variable value:

```sh
sysctl --values vm.max_map_count
```

Change variable value:

```sh
sudo sysctl --w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Learn more at [Elastisearch guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html#vm-max-map-count)