# max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144] - Permanent solution

Tags: elasticsearch, wsl-2, docker-desktop

The solution for the error: "max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]" for docker-windows wsl2 is to type the commands:

```
wsl -d docker-desktop

sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

The problem is that i need to execute it after every system restart....

why the setting removed after every restart? is the docker-desktop container builds again each time?

how can I make it permanent?

Other similar questions regarding linux and not Docker for Desktop on Windows 10 wsl.

Comment: [Elasticsearch: Max virtual memory areas vm.max\_map\_count \[65530\] is too low, increase to at least \[262144\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445846/elasticsearch-max-virtual-memory-areas-vm-max-map-count-65530-is-too-low-inc) See the first answer: `If you want to set this permanently, you need to edit /etc/sysctl.conf and set vm.max_map_count to 262144.`

Answer (score 9):

See the possible solutions here: [Elasticsearch: Max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445846/elasticsearch-max-virtual-memory-areas-vm-max-map-count-65530-is-too-low-inc/68253775)

Editing the system config (`/etc/sysctl.d/99-docker-desktop.conf` or `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count`) won't survive a Windows system restart, it only survives Docker restart. See [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5202#issuecomment-778538518).

You can however use `single-node` discovery type. Set this in the environment: `discovery.type=single-node`

`docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  es:
    image: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
```

See also:

- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5202#issuecomment-636028670

Comment: Do you have an idea why /etc/sysctl.d/99-docker-desktop.conf not survive windows restart? that files not loading on every restart?

How discovery.type=single-node can help?

Answer (score 4):

You can now use the flag `SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE` to disable the check. (Tried with Version 9.4.Community)

`$ docker run -d --name sonarqube -e SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE=true -p 9000:9000 sonarqube:latest`

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this issues recently on QNAP TS-473A NAS using Container Station. For my requirements, I need to run a ElasticSearch docker cluster using two nodes utilising `docker-compose.yml` file.
I had to connect to QNAP NAS using SSH and ran the following command which fixed the issue:

`sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`

However, this command will only set this configuration on run time session. A restart of NAS will not survive this configuration.

To permanently change the value for the vm.max_map_count setting, update the value in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. But I am not able to find this file on QNAP TS-473A NAS. Because generally, we don't restart QNAP NAS very frequent, the preceding command can fix the issue on temp basis.

**Permanent fix**

We can run any CLI commands or scripts using `autorun.sh` script of a QNAP NAS. What this `autorun.sh` script does is, it runs any valid custom commands/scripts during NAS boot up time.

Here, you can find more details of this capability: https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/faq/article/running-your-own-application-at-startup.